# OAS 5.5.0 - error while start obips1 service

Tags: linux, oracle12c, oas

I installed Oracle Analytics Server 5.5.0.

I configured it and run services. AdminServer and bi_server1 it's working ok.

But when I want run other process I have problem...I try run obips1 like:

```
./start.sh -i obips1
```

In obips1out I fin error like:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/fmwbi_oas/bi/bifoundation/web/bin/sawserver: error while loading shared libraries: libsawhttpserver643r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

File 'libsawhttpserver643r.so' exist in location: /u01/app/oracle/product/fmwbi_oas/bi/bifoundation/web/bin

And sawserver should see this file

Can anyone know why I get this error?

I installed OBIEE12 and I do not have this error, but in OAS 5.5.0 I get this error for first time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem - this is a permission problem to directory with libraries.
But at now, when I start proces I get different error:

```
[2020-07-13T10:41:02.838+02:00] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ] [tid: 8c3e8720]  [nQSError: 46136] Could not load CSF library libnqcsfwrapper64.so
```

What's wrong?